# Проверка: активна ли кнопка

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, валидация

как сделать проверку кнопки на кликабельность? К примеру  меня есть такой элемент:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался сделать проверку таким способом, не работает, всегда возвращает тру

```
function f(){
if(document.querySelector('#modals-container > div > div > div.v--modal-box.adt-modal > div > div > div.modal-content > div.step-0-content > button').disabled === true){
return true;
} else throw new Error('Validation failed!!!');
}
```

Как это правильно реализовать ?

Comment: кстати, зачем такой сложный селектор у querySelector ?

Comment: @WalkMess, скорее всего скопировано через дев тулс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что самого атрибута у элемента нет. Поэтому `.disabled` всегда `false`. Поэтому надо проверять сам атрибут в таком случае

```
if (ELEMENT.getAttribute('disabled') !== null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете делать проверку по любым параметрам. Например класс.

```js
const isClassActive = cube.classList.contains('active');
```

В данном случае, если кнопка имеет класс `active` тогда в переменную попадет true, иначе  false. Опираясь на это состояние, вы можете выставить условие.

[Node.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)